# is jquery hijacking possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

there are two ways for for handling events on click 
in JS

```
<span onclick="handle()"></span>
function handle(){......}
```

in jquery

```
<span class="handle"></span>

jQuery('.handle').click(function(){
   .....
   ....
});
```

so i want to ask attaching click event as done above in jQuery is bad practice 
is it called hijacking

Comment: Yes, of course, everything can be hooked, "hijacked", overwriten. So what? This is client side, it has nothing to do with jQuery or pure javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No .click itself can not be 'hacked' or 'hijacked' to harm your website.

Any probability of hijacking would be from the function you have written itself but it will be hard as long as all the function is client side. Jquery is very safe.